# How to make a "typeahead" for inline mentions for @ and # in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to make a twitter/facebook-esque autocomplete mentioner that would also use Angular Material's design. Unfortunately the only solutions I can find is out-of-date, or not using Angular 10 or Material. The closest thing I could find to what I'm looking for is [angular-mentions](http://dmacfarlane.github.io/angular-mentions/) and [Algolia Autocomplete Textarea](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/resources/ui-and-ux-patterns/in-depth/autocomplete/tutorials/autocomplete-textarea/) (I don't use Algolia, fyi).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.